# different result on different os with same xml layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Same xml layout code causes different look on same resolution/density device.
Please see the attached images below.
Can any body tell me what can be the problem?
I tried it with 2 textview but it's consistent with all os. Only problem is when i use button then and then this problem arises.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnHello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnHello"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: does screen size of the device vary?

Comment: No,same screen size 480x800 and same density - 240

Comment: how about the actual size in inches?

Comment: 4 inch for all screen